# Why I can not call base constructor method with an argument?

Tags: c#, oop

```
public class GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    internal DbContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }
    //snip
}

public class MyRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : GenericRepository<TEntity>
{
        public MyRepository(DbContext context) : base(context){ }
        //snip
}
```

I extended the `GenericRepository` class, and to use base's member variables I need to call Base's constructor in child's constructor. But I got an error that says:

> 'object' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Even though the `GenericRepository` has constructor.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because your "base class" is `object`, not `GenericRepository<TEntity>`.  You added a constraint on `TEntity`, you did not inherit from `GenericRepository<TEntity>`.  Maybe you meant this:

```
public class MyRepository<TEntity> : GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public MyRepository(DbContext context) : base(context){ }
```

Comment: So it's a typo question I guess?

Comment: @DavidG I see it more as a misunderstanding between generic constraints and inheritance.  I don't think the OP _meant_ to type inheritance and typed a generic constraint accidentally, but it's a semantic argument.

Comment: Well I suppose the specific error message may help someone else in future, so I'm not totally against this being closed.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, it's a pretty narrow problem.  I actually started to put the answer as a comment but then realized that the comment was the complete answer and not just a hint as to what the answer is.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change `MyRepository`'s base class to `GenericRepository<TEntity>`
Also you need to leave `where TEntity : class` restriction

```
public class MyRepository<TEntity> : GenericRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public MyRepository(object context)
        :base(context)
    {

    }
}
```